# executar/chamar uma página remotamente

Tags: c#, .net

Quero executar uma página remota, não me interessa saber o que essa página faz, apenas preciso executa-la e esperar ela carregar 100% para executar outra, e assim por diante.

Não preciso recuperar nenhuma informação dessa página.

Pode ser em Windows.Form, Console App. com qualquer componente, etc.
Tentei com XmlDocument, RestSharp e nada.

Hoje a única maneira que consegui foi com webbrowser, porém fiz botões manuais, não consegui fazer ele entender quando a página é 100% carregada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe `WebClient`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

```
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.OpenRead("urlAqui");
    // ou
    // wc.DownloadString("urlAqui");
}
```

Esta classe tem vários métodos úteis pra explorar, dê uma olhada no link.

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado.

Então ficou assim o código para ler a página, conforme eu precisava:

Ele le a página, preciso testar com uma página grande que demora em torno de 2min, pra ser executada.

```
  string url = "http://www.url.com.br";
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                Stream data = wc.OpenRead(url);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

                textBox1.Text = s;
            }
```

Comment: Legal. Se demorar muito, você pode usar o método Async, que da pra processar paralelamente.

Comment: seria possível de vc me mostrar algo como conseguiria fazer o código acima com o Async me parece ser muito promissor o Async

Comment: Você tem que assinar o evento `OnOpenReadCompleted` e chamar o método `OpenReadAsync()`. Quando acabar de ler a página, ele vai executar o evento. Se não precisa esperar que termine a leitura para fazer alguma coisa, basta chamar o método e pronto.

Comment: Só mais uma observação a respeito da comunidade. Nos casos que você quer adicionar informações, sempre utilize a opção de editar a sua pergunta. Este espaço é destinado à respostas, blz?